# Tensorflow Lite Object Detection with Custom AutoML Model

Tags: android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite, automl

I like to test the Object Detection Example of TFLite.

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android

The example with the default Model works great. But I want to test a custom Model generated from AutoML. When I am replace the "detect.tflite" and "labelmap fille" in the "\src\main\assets" directory and build then the App crashes after launch.

My Model is very simple ... can detect only 2 objects (Tiger and Lion). And my labelmap file contains below:

???
Tiger
Lion

Also I comment the line "//apply from:'download_model.gradle'" in "build.gradle" to stop the download of default Model and use my custom Model from asset.

I new in both Android and this ML space. I'll be glad if anyone can advise for App crash after launch with custom AutoML Model.

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: You should provide more detail as to where/what is the AutoML model file generated (perhaps a link to source). Realize that Tensorflow Lite only knows about `.tflite` files.

Comment: Hi yes sure. In google AutoML platform ... it provides GUI to generate Models with zero coding. Where I uploaded all of my images, make Bounding Box and start Training (by selecting Edge). After few Hr training is over and I can download my model file in .tflite format This .tflite file I used in Android Studio Object detection example but the App crashes after launch.

Comment: I would double check that your input and output vectors match any Android app you are replacing the default model in. Otherwise you should show what is crashing, logcat etc.

Answer (score 0):

Two probable errors on log might be:

`Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 1080000 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 270000 bytes.` Modify TF_OD_API_INPUT_SIZE accordingly.

`tflite ml google [1, 20, 4] and a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].` Modify NUM_DETECTIONS according to custom model.